# How could I fix the wrong message "Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done" in pymc4

Tags: python, jupyter

I am running my Bayesian model using pymc4.But It
crushed  when I do the sample metheod. I wanna know where my problem was. Here is my code

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
import aesara.tensor as at
from aesara.compile.ops import as_op
assert pm.__version__ == '4.0.0b6'


data = [0.05 + i for i in np.random.uniform(-0.05, 0.2, 1000)]

##https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/latest/learn/core_notebooks/pymc_overview.html?highlight=switch#case-study-2-coal-mining-disasters 
## example :Arbitary deterministics. I changed the function in the url above
@as_op(itypes=[at.dscalar, at.dscalar], otypes=[at.dscalar])
def piecewise_timespan_label(back, forward):
    td = forward - back
    if td >= 12:
        return 1
    elif td >= 8:
        return 0.9
    elif td >= 6:
        return 0.8
    elif td >= 4:
        return 0.6
    elif td >= 2:
        return 0.4
    elif td >= 1:
        return 0.2
    elif td >= 0.5:
        return 0.1
    elif td >= 0.05:
        return 0.08
    else:
        return 0.05


with pm.Model() as model_deterministic:
    back = pm.Exponential("back", 0.2)
    forward = pm.Exponential("forward", 0.2)
    ratio_est = piecewise_timespan_label(back, forward)
    eps = pm.HalfCauchy("eps", 0.5)
    y = pm.Normal("y", ratio_est, sigma=eps, observed=data)

with model_deterministic:
    idata = pm.sample(1000)

print('here')
```

Here is my wrong message:

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

My system is window 10 21H2
I am running it on
vscode jupyter:v2022.4.1021342353

aesara:2.5.1

pymc:'4.0.0b6'

numpy:1.23.0rc1

Thank in advance for reply

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a lack of available memory from your computer. On windows, you can check this very easily by opening your task manager, and looking at memory usage in the Performance tab while running the code.

One way you can solve this problem is by taking only a subset of your dataset. If you don't want to do that, you can try to use Colab, for example.

Hope it helps.